# How to generate dxi-column list dynamically from typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, dx-data-grid

We are developing an angular application. dxdatagrid is used to display data. 
In dxdatagrid is it possible to generate columns from typescript?

Please see the below code snippet

< dx-data-grid id="EmployeeGrid"

```
            [dataSource]="EmployeeList">        
    <dxi-column dataField="FirstName"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="LastName"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

Here I want to generate the "FirstName" and "LastName" from Typescript.

Please any one help to achieve the same

Thanks

Krishnan

Comment: Please follow the example in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738343/how-to-create-dxi-column-with-datatype-dynamically-in-dxdatagrid/57395576#57395576

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```html
<dxi-column *ngFor="let col of cols" dataField="{{col.dataField}}" caption="{{col.caption}}"></dxi-column>
```

cols is a attribute in ts file, and it is array,so the column count is the length of array